# Double Choco: I love myself

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

Rules of Double Choco: (copied from [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/93768/71652))

> - Divide the grid into regions by drawing along some of the dotted lines.
> - Each region should have one group of gray cells and one group of white cells; both of these groups should be connected.
> - The two groups in a region should be the same size and shape (but they may be rotated or reflected).
> - Each number tells the size of each of the groups in its region. Not every region needs to have a number.

Because my username contains three B's (one in uppercase and two lowercase), here's a puzzle containing the three letters "Bbb". Enjoy!

[image]

You can solve it online [on Penpa](https://swaroopg92.github.io/penpa-edit/?m=solve&p=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).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like so?

> [image]

The "1" region is a given, and the white splotch at the bottom left consists entirely of squares in numbered regions. There are only so many ways (two, to be exact) to split that splotch, and one of them immediately leads to problems (r5c1 can only connect to white areas that won't be able to house the required white group).

The counterpart for the "5" group then has three possible orientations. One of them forces a 4 sized group to connect to the 3 in the top row, and another one cuts r5c1 into a region without any white squares. After choosing the third option, you get forced regions pretty much all the way to the end, at least as long as you notice that r7c4 cannot connect to the whites at the bottom right, as there can only be white groups of size 3 or less in there.